# Move div when you click and hold a button

Tags: jquery, mousedown, mouseup

Basically I want my player to move when I click and hold a button using JQuery's .mousedown function. The problem is, the player doesn't continously move left, he just moves once. I want him to keep moving left until I mouseup.

Here's my code:

```
$('#arrowRight').mousedown(function() {
      $('#player').animate({'left':'+=20px'});
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var isDown = false;
$arrowRight = $("#arrowRight");
$arrowLeft = $("#arrowLeft");
$arrowRight.mousedown(function(){isDown = true;});
$arrowLeft.mousedown(function(){isDown = true;});
$(document).mouseup(function(){
    if(isDown){
        isDown = false;
    }
}); 

$arrowRight.mousedown(function() {movePlayer('+=20');});
$arrowLeft.mousedown(function() {movePlayer('-=20');});

function movePlayer(intMovement){
  $( "#player" ).animate({
        'left': intMovement +'px'
  }, 100, function() {
      if (isDown){
          movePlayer(intMovement);
      }
  });
}
```

**[Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4c3sgtze/4/)**

Comment: @NotToBrag: Check the updated answer for both right and left solution if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link
http://remysharp.com/2006/12/15/jquery-mousehold-event/
A plugin for mousehold event. It should work in your case.
You can also write your own by setting a time interval in your mouse down event to trigger for every 0.1 second.I believe the above plugin does the same, but is readymade.
HTH.